# SOLR Out Of Memory Error when reading/indexing a large index

Tags: performance, memory, solr, out-of-memory

I'm running into a OOM error with Solr, when indexing large amounts of data. I know the general advice would be to split the index into shards, but actually this is already the case.  I'm indexing shards, and further splitting is at this point not an option. I want to understand what is happening and why am I getting this error and if there is anything I can do about it other than splitting or giving more RAM.

I would be sad if the RAM consumption was linear (or worse) in this case, I'd rather have it sub-linear.

The case is I'm indexing documents with random strings (thus the dictionary is very very large). Each document has a couple of 20-30 chars fields and one field about 200-500 chars. The index size in every shard is about 250-260GB, each solr instance handling this index has about 4GB of memory. When the OOM occured, after restarting it the Solr HeapDump looked about the same, so it's probably not tied to indexing but the Solr Searcher. Just before the OOM the heapdump's largest objects look like the following:

```
<tree type="Heap walker - Biggest objects">
  <object leaf="false" class="org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore" objectId="0xf02c" type="instance" retainedBytes="120456864" retainedPercent="97.4">
    <outgoing leaf="false" class="org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher" objectId="0xfb52" type="instance" retainedBytes="120383232" retainedPercent="97.3" referenceType="not specified" referenceName="[transitive reference]">
      <outgoing leaf="false" class="org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlySegmentReader" objectId="0x1018e" type="instance" retainedBytes="8161688" retainedPercent="6.6" referenceType="not specified" referenceName="[transitive reference]"/>
      <outgoing leaf="false" class="org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlySegmentReader" objectId="0x10185" type="instance" retainedBytes="8148072" retainedPercent="6.6" referenceType="not specified" referenceName="[transitive reference]"/>
      <outgoing leaf="false" class="org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlySegmentReader" objectId="0x10188" type="instance" retainedBytes="8138232" retainedPercent="6.6" referenceType="not specified" referenceName="[transitive reference]"/>
      <outgoing leaf="false" class="org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlySegmentReader" objectId="0x10186" type="instance" retainedBytes="8129160" retainedPercent="6.6" referenceType="not specified" referenceName="[transitive reference]"/>
      <outgoing leaf="false" class="org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlySegmentReader" objectId="0x10191" type="instance" retainedBytes="8124608" retainedPercent="6.6" referenceType="not specified" referenceName="[transitive reference]"/>
      <outgoing leaf="false" class="org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlySegmentReader" objectId="0x1018a" type="instance" retainedBytes="8123144" retainedPercent="6.6" referenceType="not specified" referenceName="[transitive reference]"/>

      <outgoing leaf="false" class="org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlySegmentReader" objectId="0x10192" type="instance" retainedBytes="8100904" retainedPercent="6.5" referenceType="not specified" referenceName="[transitive reference]"/>
      <outgoing leaf="false" class="org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlySegmentReader" objectId="0x10190" type="instance" retainedBytes="8097984" retainedPercent="6.5" referenceType="not specified" referenceName="[transitive reference]"/>
      <outgoing leaf="false" class="org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlySegmentReader" objectId="0x1018b" type="instance" retainedBytes="8096160" retainedPercent="6.5" referenceType="not specified" referenceName="[transitive reference]"/>
      <outgoing leaf="false" class="org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlySegmentReader" objectId="0x1018d" type="instance" retainedBytes="8081656" retainedPercent="6.5" referenceType="not specified" referenceName="[transitive reference]"/>
      <outgoing leaf="false" class="org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlySegmentReader" objectId="0x10187" type="instance" retainedBytes="8042504" retainedPercent="6.5" referenceType="not specified" referenceName="[transitive reference]"/>
      <outgoing leaf="false" class="org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlySegmentReader" objectId="0x1018c" type="instance" retainedBytes="8039336" retainedPercent="6.5" referenceType="not specified" referenceName="[transitive reference]"/>
      <outgoing leaf="false" class="org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlySegmentReader" objectId="0x10189" type="instance" retainedBytes="8036952" retainedPercent="6.5" referenceType="not specified" referenceName="[transitive reference]"/>
      <outgoing leaf="false" class="org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlySegmentReader" objectId="0x1018f" type="instance" retainedBytes="7948568" retainedPercent="6.4" referenceType="not specified" referenceName="[transitive reference]"/>
      <outgoing leaf="false" class="org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlySegmentReader" objectId="0x10195" type="instance" retainedBytes="832448" retainedPercent="0.7" referenceType="not specified" referenceName="[transitive reference]"/>

      <outgoing leaf="false" class="org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlySegmentReader" objectId="0x10196" type="instance" retainedBytes="830584" retainedPercent="0.7" referenceType="not specified" referenceName="[transitive reference]"/>
      <outgoing leaf="false" class="org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlySegmentReader" objectId="0x10194" type="instance" retainedBytes="829232" retainedPercent="0.7" referenceType="not specified" referenceName="[transitive reference]"/>
      <outgoing leaf="false" class="org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlySegmentReader" objectId="0x10197" type="instance" retainedBytes="828808" retainedPercent="0.7" referenceType="not specified" referenceName="[transitive reference]"/>
      <outgoing leaf="false" class="org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlySegmentReader" objectId="0x10198" type="instance" retainedBytes="827312" retainedPercent="0.7" referenceType="not specified" referenceName="[transitive reference]"/>
      <outgoing leaf="false" class="org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlySegmentReader" objectId="0x10199" type="instance" retainedBytes="824736" retainedPercent="0.7" referenceType="not specified" referenceName="[transitive reference]"/>
      <outgoing leaf="false" class="org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlySegmentReader" objectId="0x1019a" type="instance" retainedBytes="822608" retainedPercent="0.7" referenceType="not specified" referenceName="[transitive reference]"/>
      <outgoing leaf="false" class="org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlySegmentReader" objectId="0x10193" type="instance" retainedBytes="783424" retainedPercent="0.6" referenceType="not specified" referenceName="[transitive reference]"/>
      <cutoff objectCount="96" totalSizeBytes="534976" maximumSingleSizeBytes="87560"/>
    </outgoing>

    <cutoff objectCount="53" totalSizeBytes="73496" maximumSingleSizeBytes="40992"/>
  </object>
  <object leaf="false" class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader" objectId="0xdf88" type="instance" retainedBytes="420208" retainedPercent="0.3"/>
  <object leaf="false" class="org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig" objectId="0xe5f5" type="instance" retainedBytes="184976" retainedPercent="0.1"/>
 .....
```

The jmap simple dump looks like this:

```
Attaching to process ID 27000, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 20.5-b03

using thread-local object allocation.
Parallel GC with 2 thread(s)

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 70
   MaxHeapSize      = 268435456 (256.0MB)
   NewSize          = 1310720 (1.25MB)
   MaxNewSize       = 17592186044415 MB
   OldSize          = 5439488 (5.1875MB)
   NewRatio         = 2
   SurvivorRatio    = 8
   PermSize         = 21757952 (20.75MB)
   MaxPermSize      = 85983232 (82.0MB)

Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 31719424 (30.25MB)
   used     = 17420488 (16.61347198486328MB)
   free     = 14298936 (13.636528015136719MB)
   54.92056854500258% used
From Space:
   capacity = 26673152 (25.4375MB)
   used     = 10550856 (10.062080383300781MB)
   free     = 16122296 (15.375419616699219MB)
   39.55608995892199% used
To Space:
   capacity = 27000832 (25.75MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 27000832 (25.75MB)
   0.0% used
PS Old Generation
   capacity = 178978816 (170.6875MB)
   used     = 168585552 (160.7757110595703MB)
   free     = 10393264 (9.911788940429688MB)
   94.19302002757689% used
PS Perm Generation
   capacity = 42008576 (40.0625MB)
   used     = 41690016 (39.758697509765625MB)
   free     = 318560 (0.303802490234375MB)
   99.24167865152106% used
```

I don't see here anything that would give me any clues as to how to deal with it, other than just giving more RAM, which in the general case is not a solution, I'd like to know what's going on, why is the Searcher and it's ReadOnlySegmentReaders taking all the memory and do they really have to, can I do something about it?

UPDATE:
I've done a test with a much smaller dictionary of about 150 thousand words (not random words), I reached the index size of about 350GB and there are no OOME, so this is not directly connected to index size, probably has to do more with the term vector size (unique terms). But still I'd like to understand the limitations I have and how can I go around them.

Comment: What's the operating system you are using? Is it 64 bit or 32 bit?

Comment: UPDATE:
I've done a test with a much smaller dictionary of about 150 thousand words (not random words), I reached the index size of about 350GB and there are no OOME, so this is not directly connected to index size, probably has to do more with the term vector size (unique terms). But still I'd like to understand the limitations I have and how can I go around them.

Comment: Are you using random strings as test data? If so, you might want to use a power law (Zipf) distribution rather than a flat distribution. Many of Solr's algorithms are optimized for the distributions usually seen in text. The same thing holds for test queries, a flat distribution of queries can give an unrealistically low cache hit ratio.

Comment: @WalterUnderwood - interesting. Yes I was using random strings, in the mainstream project now I'm using a real-world text generator, and I don't have those problems, but in a branch I still explore the random string version, in order to discover and understand the limits my system will have that are imposed by Solr. So at the moment I'm not that concerned with cache hit ratio, rather than understanding why such a data corpus causes the whole thing to crash with OOME.

Answer (score 0):

Its up to you to get all of your documents indexed on each 'shard' of your server farm. There is no out of the box support for distributed indexing, but your method can be as simple as a round robin technique: Index each document to the next server in the circle. A simple hashing system would also work, and the Solr Wiki suggests uniqueId.hashCode() % numServers as an adequate hashing function.

Keep in mind that Solr does not calculate universal term/doc frequencies. At a large scale, its not likely to matter that tf/idf is calculated at the shard level - however, if your collection is heavily skewed in its distribution across servers, you might take issue with the relevance results. Its probably best to randomly distribute documents to your shards.
note>>>>>>> try to use hashcode instead of random strings to index documents

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. I am indexing shards. It's done in parallel, using Hadoop. And given the specific text corpus that I mentioned those shards crash during indexing this data at about the size 260GB of index per shard, and I already now that this OOM is not directly connected to the index size, because I indexed some other data (not random strings) which gave me a 360GB index and the shards survived ... anyway I guess you were answering a different question, thanks for the interest anyway ;)